How can I use vba to insert a row below each row that contains "2024" in a specified column, and in that new row enter "2025" in same column?
I am downloading sales history from ERP system and want to add a row for next year's forecasting.
ERP export image:

..as text:
Employee.Employee   Company Product Year    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec Total

Employee.1  Customer A  Product A   2023                                1                   1
Employee.1  Customer A  Product A   2024                        2                           2
Employee.1  Customer A  Product B   2024                        4                           4
Employee.1  Customer A  Product C   2024                        5                           5
Employee.1  Customer A  Product D   2024                        3                           3
Employee.1  Customer A  Product E   2024                        3                           3
Employee.1  Customer A  Product F   2023                                39  22              61
Employee.1  Customer A  Product F   2024                        19                          19

I have no vba training,,,just know there's a better way than manually. Appreciate any help/advice.  The below works for adding the blank row. Now how do I get "2025" entered into Col D of newly inserted Row?
Sub Macro1()
    Dim RngToCheck As Range
    Set RngToCheck = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoiced Tons by Customer by Mo").Range("D3:D5000")
    Dim ValToFind As Long
    ValToFind = 2024

    Dim i As Long
    For i = RngToCheck.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If RngToCheck(i).Value = ValToFind Then
            RngToCheck(i + 1).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next i
End Sub


Try this out:
Sub Macro1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, RngToCheck As Range, ValToFind As Long, i As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoiced Tons by Customer by Mo")
    'only check the occupied range
    Set RngToCheck = ws.Range("D3:D" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
    ValToFind = 2024  'consider using Const instead of a variable here...

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False     'faster if you do this
    For i = RngToCheck.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        With RngToCheck.Cells(i)
            If .Value = ValToFind Then
                .offset(1).EntireRow.Insert 'add a row below the found value
                .offset(1).Value = 2025     'insert value on added row
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub


Many thanks for your response. I encounter a 'subcript out of range' error on this line:  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoiced Tons by Customer by Mo") . I substitute "Sheet1" for "Invoiced Tons by Customer by Mo" in the macro and rename the tab as Sheet1, and re-run the macro. The subscript error no longer occurs. However, the macro does not affect the worksheet.

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoiced Tons by Customer by Mo") is from your posted code though?  Did you mean ActiveWorkbook ?

Is the sheet being modified in the same workbook as the VBA?

Worksheets is the correct object. The worksheet name is created by the ERP report export. I've tried overwriting the worksheet name manually to match "Invoiced Tons by Customer by Mo" , just in case there are phantom characters from the import, but still no success.

And the VBA is in the same workbook as the worksheet?

No, I have the VBA in 'Personal.XLSB'

OK then you should use Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoiced Tons by Customer by Mo")   If your code in in personal.xlsb then ThisWorkook would refer to your personal macro workbook, not the exported report you want to modify.

Changed to ActiveWorkbook.  Success.  Thank you!

Good to hear you got it working. Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.
